# No Output while filtering records in spring data mongodb

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

**Problem**

I am trying to retrieve records based on brand,vehicle Mode etc of user but I am not receiving any records.

**Task I did**

I used mongoTemplate to retrieve record.I am applying condition that if the field is not null I will retrieve otherwise I will not retrieve.

**Below is my Code**

**Vehicle Model**

```
@Document
public class Vehicle extends AbstractEntity {
@Id
private String id;
private String yearOfBuying;
private String brand;
private String model;
private String mileage;
private String availableFuel;
private String vehicleRcNo;
private String vehicleNumber;
private String rcImageId;
private String description;
private String vehicleName;
private VEHICLE_TYPE vehicleType;
private VEHICLE_MODE vehicleMode;
private FUEL_TYPE fuelType;
private List<WALLET_TYPE> walletTypeList;
private List<AVAILABLE_WITH> availableWithList;
private List<PRICE_TYPE> priceTypeList;
private boolean availability = true;
private String sellAddress;
private String city;
private String state;
private String pinCode;
private String userId;
@GeoSpatialIndexed(type = GeoSpatialIndexType.GEO_2DSPHERE)
private double[] location;
private float securityAmount;
private long availableFrom;
private long availableTo;
private String aboutVehicle;
private float discountPercentage;
private String dos;
private String dont;
private long pollutionDate;
private String pollutionImageId;
private long endInsuranceDate;
private String insuranceImageId;
private float pricePerDay;
private float pricePerDayWithDriver;
private float pricePerHour;
private float pricePerHourWithDriver;
private float pricePerWeek;
private float pricePerWeekWithDriver;
private float pricePerMonth;
private float pricePerMonthWithDriver;
```

**VehicleController**

```
@GetMapping(value = "/searchByBrand")
ApiResponse<List<Vehicle>> searchRecords() {
    return ApiResponse.success().object(vehicleService.searchByBrandOrVehicleTypeOrFuelType("Mahindra","BIKE","DIESEL"));
}
```

**interface VehicleService**

```
List<Vehicle> searchByBrandOrVehicleTypeOrFuelType(String brand,String vehicleType,String fuelType);
```

**VehicleServiceImpl**

```
@Override
public List<Vehicle> searchByBrandOrVehicleTypeOrFuelType(String brand,String vehicleType,String fuelType) {
    return vehicleRepository.searchByBrandOrVehicleTypeOrFuelType(brand,vehicleType,fuelType);
}
```

**VehicleRepository**

```
public interface VehicleRepository extends MongoRepository<Vehicle, String>,VehicleRepositoryCustom {
```

**VehicleRepositoryCustom**

```
public interface VehicleRepositoryCustom {
//Advance query
List<Vehicle> searchByBrandOrVehicleTypeOrFuelType(String searchPattern,String vehicleType,String fuelType);
```

}

**VehicleRepositoryImpl**

```
public class VehicleRepositoryImpl implements VehicleRepositoryCustom{
@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
private Class<Vehicle> clazz = Vehicle.class;

@Override
public List<Vehicle> searchByBrandOrVehicleTypeOrFuelType(String brand,String vehicleType,String fuelType) {
    Query query = new Query();
    if(brand!=null){
        System.out.println("Executed Not null");
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("brand").is(brand));
    }else {
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("brand").exists(false));
    }
    if(vehicleType!=null){
        System.out.println("Executed Not null");
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("vehicleType").is(vehicleType));
    }else {
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("vehicleType").exists(false));
    }
    if(fuelType!=null){
        System.out.println("Executed Not null");
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("fuelType").is(fuelType));
    }else {
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("fuelType").exists(false));
    }
    return mongoTemplate.find(query, clazz);
}
```

**Output Expected**

Records with matching conditions

**Output Shown**

[]

> Can anyone guide me how to apply query  correctly?

Comment: Can you add sample document from your collection ?

Comment: @Veeram  updated the same.

Comment: Sorry I was looking for document from your collection. Can you provide ?

Comment: @Veeram Vehicle Model is the Document.

Comment: Okay Are your field name camel case in database too ?  Can you output `query.toString()` before the mongo template call to console and see what it displays ? And is your expected query ? And you can run the query in mongo shell to verify the results and work backwards from there to find the root cause for the issue. Try to run a simple query and see if it return any results.